# How to hide vertical/horizontal lines in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am using Pyqt4 for GUI programming in python. How can I hide vertical or horizontal lines in QTableWidget?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
yourTableWidget.setShowGrid(False)
```

Unfortunately there seems to be no good way to do this via Stylesheets. A workaround is to set `gridline-color:` the same as `background-color:`.

If you want to disable just vertical **or** horizontal lines, turn the grid off in code, and draw the borders per item with the `QTableView::item` selector.