# border and text qss settings at QTableView

Tags: c++, css, qt, qtstylesheets

Here's I am trying to do that: 
[image]

but I set that stylesheet in my `QTableView`:

```
QTableView {
    gridline-color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
    }
QHeaderView {background-color: transparent;

}
QHeaderView::section{
border-style: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: transparent;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-top:5px;
}
QTableView QTableCornerButton::section {
     bottom-style:none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);

 }
```

Result is this:[image]

I can handle with size problem for future but there is two main problem over here:

1.Column text between border there isnt any space, I did `margin-top:5px;` and `margin-bottom:5px;` but it changed for all `QHeaderView` not only `QHeaderView`'s Text. (**Solution is use padding instead of margin**)

2.Every row has a right ,left even top border. I dont want that.

I tried this:

```
QTableView QTableCornerButton::section {
     border-style:none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);

 }
```

Unfortunately there is a problem at `QTableCornerButton:section` it doesn't work...

Thank you for any helping

Comment: Just a remark: You can't get a table with just horizontal grid lines and without vertical ones. There has to be either complete grid or no grid. To obtain what is on your first picture, you have to implement a delegate with custom painting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note : I haven't verified, these are just suggestions to try, please upload the output if needed*

**1 - What do you mean by "it changed for all QHeaderView not only QHeaderView's Text"?**

Maybe you expected to set margin only to the headerview's content (text) : in that case use the **padding** not margin.

```
QHeaderView::section{
/* your style */
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-top:5px;
}
```

**2 - Every row has a right ,left even top border. I dont want that.**

```
QTableView {
    /* sone additional style */
    gridline-color: cyan
    background-color: cyan
}

QTableView::item
{
    border-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

I would try to use the border-style (set to none) as you did in QHeaderView's style.

Edit : You certainly must disable the showgrid's option of your QTableView by code to make it a working solution

```
tableView.setShowGrid(false);
```

Comment: yeah first solution is awesome but second didnt work it isnt change anything.

Comment: And If you remove the gridline part ?

Comment: yeah i checked now it doesnt work maybe we cant do with qss

Comment: I looked at other posts : there is no way to get the behavior you want with qss.
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455445/how-to-hide-vertical-horizontal-lines-in-qtablewidget
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938636/how-to-set-stylesheet-for-the-current-item-in-qtableview

Comment: okey i will check how i can do with QStyleDeleagateItem. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Edited with a last try with QTableView:item. Let me know.

Comment: okey your solution is correct can you  
in addition to add your post to "you must disable showgrid" ? because if i dont , it doesnt work. Maybe someone miss that. Thank you again